# What's wrong with Chrome App client_id?

Tags: google-chrome-app, identity

Why client_id in manifest.json of chrome app sample from Google look this

```
"client_id": "497291774654.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

but when i try to get chrome app client id from my gdc it look this

```
123456668721-442g9f5drmq5whyeuokni9j59c7qq4an.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

clearly, the formats dont look the same. 
when i try to replace my client_id to the sample, it's behaving differently.

Answer (score 0):

I create an OAuth client ID to confirm this format. And you are correct I get the same format like the one that you post. Maybe the sample client_id in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) only represent the first 12 numbers of the client ID. Try to create another client ID for the same project, you will notice that the number part which is the first 12 numbers like in the example from the documentation will not change.